# Is there a way to plot multiple scatterplots on the same visualization in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Context: I created a chart with two lines in Power BI that plots time-to-degree as a function of a test score; each line corresponds to a measurement based on a unique set of filters. The filters can have overlapping data (ex. one line is filtered to females, the second is filtered to Caucasians).

[Line Graph With 2 Measures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq9AT.png)

I've been asked to turn this into a scatterplot, but obviously I'm not able to put in more than one Y value (TTD for filter1, TTD for filter2) even though the X (test score) is the same for both. I've been trying add-ins, Excel, Python, and I'm pretty lost on what to do next. What would be the best route to create this type of visualization in Power BI?

Example Data:

| Sex | Race | Score | TTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | W | 32 | 4.5 |
| M | B | 27 | 5 |
| F | A | 30 | 4 |
| M | W | 25 | 3.75 |

[Ideal Final Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUnDi.png)

Info: X = score (high_test), Y = ttd

Blue dots filtered by race, red dots filtered by sex

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Cant follow your example data vs final product

Comment: @MikeHoney Thanks for your input. I added the following info to my question: X is score/high_test, Y is ttd, the blue dots are the data filtered by race, and the red dots are the data filtered by sex. Is there any more information I should provide?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Editor to transform the data - select the first two columns and choose Unpivot Selected Columns from the right-click menu.

Then you can build the Scatter Chart visual with the Values column in the Details well and Attribute column in the Legend well.